# Web Page not Anchoring in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am attempting to have the page go to a div section of the page based on what they click. I have the div for each section id'd with the proper tag. I have done a test where I can load the page and type `url.com/services#insertidhere` and it will go to the correct location. The issue is when I try to implement it in the state it won't go to the location. It just goes to the page normally even though the URL shown is correct.

**HTML Index Snippet**

```
<div ng-repeat="x in blue.services">
    <div class="wrapIMG">
        <img src="{{x.icon}}" />
        <img class="clone" src="{{x.icon}}" />
    </div>
    <h4>{{x.title}}</h4>
    <hr/>
    <p>{{x.text}}</p>
    <a ui-sref="services({id: x.title})" class="button2">About This</a>
</div>
```

**myapp.js Snippet**

```
app.config(function($stateProvider){
    $stateProvider
        .state('index', {
          url:"/",
            templateUrl: 'main.html',
            data: {
                cssId: 'home'
            }
        })
        .state('services', {
            url: "/services/#:id",
            templateUrl: 'services.html',
            data: {
                cssId: 'services'
            }
        })
});
```

Services HTML Snippet

```
<section class="no-padding" style="" id="[id equal to x.title]"> ...</section>
<section class="no-padding" style="" id="[id equal to x.title]"> ...</section>
<section class="no-padding" style="" id="[id equal to x.title]"> ...</section>
```

I believe the issue has to be with `.state` URL but it shows correctly in the URL but it just isn't going to the location.

Answer (score 0):

Angular uses the `#` in URLs for page routing (so do many other SPA frameworks).

To anchor the link to a specific id on a page, use the [`$anchorScroll` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll).

Example:

```
<div id="scrollArea" ng-controller="ScrollController">
  <a ng-click="gotoBottom()">Go to bottom</a>
  <a id="bottom"></a> You're at the bottom!
</div>

<script>
  angular.module('anchorScrollExample', [])
  .controller('ScrollController', ['$scope', '$location', '$anchorScroll',
    function($scope, $location, $anchorScroll) {
      $scope.gotoBottom = function() {
        // set the location.hash to the id of
        // the element you wish to scroll to.
        $location.hash('bottom');

        // call $anchorScroll()
        $anchorScroll();
      };
    }]);
</script>
```

Comment: Apologies in advanced if this sounds stupid because I am in the process of learning angular but how am I suppose to get this call working when the call is suppose to happen on another html page. So basically it would need to load a new page and then scroll to the section based on what was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.toPage = function(){$state.go('index');}
```

Did you try this?